# Не могу понять тернарный оператор

Tags: c++

Хай. Ребята, недавно начал изучение плюсов, столкнулся с тернарным оператором... Застрял на этой теме. У меня есть задание, я его выполнил на If-else, но нужно его выполнить используя тернарный оператор... Подскажите, как это сделать?)))

```
    double h;
    double q;
    cout << "Введите число h: ";
    cin >> h;
    if(sqrt(h) <= 3.75) {
    q = (1 + h) / pow(h, 4);
    } else {
        q = log (h);
    }
    cout << "Q = " << q << endl;
```

Comment: Чё там понимать? `if (A) {B} else {C}` == `A ? B : C`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (A) B; else C;
```

можно записать как

```
A ? B : C;
```

только учесть 1. приоритеты операторов и 2. что `B` и `C` вообще-то выражения, так что ваше

```
if(sqrt(h) <= 3.75) {
    q = (1 + h) / pow(h, 4);
} else {
    q = log (h);
}
```

лучше записывать не как

```
(sqrt(h) <= 3.75) ? q = (1 + h) / pow(h, 4) : q = log (h);
```

а как

```
q = (sqrt(h) <= 3.75) ? (1 + h) / pow(h, 4) : log (h);
```

Еще одно следствие из того, что `B` и `C` - выражения то, что их типы должны быть одинаковы/приводимы. Записать

```
int a; const char * b;
(z > 0) ? a = 2 : b = "xxx";
```

не получится - тут только `if-else`.